# Check periodically if folder has been created in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a list of folders in a text file. I want to periodically check if all of these folders have been deployed into a directory using bash script.

I cannot use `notify` as not all of my servers are able to use this command.

Comment: The question is: once you've checked the existence of those folders, what do you want to do with them? Be wary of race conditions.

Comment: Once i check existance of those folders I want to echo a message for the user that the application is ready to use.

Comment: Using a filesystem for synchronization is an invitation to wrong. Use a socket, use an http server, use a serial port, just don't use a file system.

Comment: How periodically? Can you use cron ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use cron for this task. I need to check if every 2 seconds when user starts the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about do it in a `while` loop with `sleep` command. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    # flag represents if the app is ready, 1=ready, 0=not ready
    is_ready=1
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        # ignore empty line
        [[ -n "$line" ]] || continue
        if [[ ! -d "$line" ]]; then
            is_ready=0
            break
        fi
    done < "path/to/folders_list.txt"

    if [[ $is_ready -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "App is ready"
        break
    else
        # idle for 10 seconds
        sleep 10
    fi
done
```

Comment: It works perfectly! To anyone who will find this script useful please keep in mind that you have to have full directory to the folder you are testing in folder_list.txt